Flutter - The webpage at intent://play.google.com/store/ could not be loaded because net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
My application has an embedded WebView that loads a webpage from my server. On this webpage, I added the image of my new app and a download link to my new app. The webpage is loading fine. When a user clicks on this link on the webpage the user is redirected to my app on the Google Play Store. The HTML anchor tag is:
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app.id">Download App</a>

If I open this webpage on a normal browser from my PC and click on the Download App link, it works fine but if I open this webpage on the Flutter app embedded WebView and click on the Download App link, it gives the following error:
The webpage at intent://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app.id&pcampaignid=web_auto_redirect could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

That's the code responsible for opening the embedded WebView:
await launchUrl(Uri.parse("MyWebPageURL"), mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView, webViewConfiguration: WebViewConfiguration(headers: <String,String>{'authorization': webPageLogins}));

Tried with mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication still didn't worked.
Edit:
Date: 22 December 2024
Version: url_launcher: ^6.3.1
I found here that url_launcher currently doesn't support URLs with intent:// protocol.
Any solution to this issue?
